# Path `comment` is required. MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I don't understand why I get this error. This is my controller:

```
export const createProductReview = async (req, res) => {
  const { rating, comment } = req.body;

  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

  if (product) {
    const alreadyReviewed = product.reviews.find(
      r => r.user.toString() === req.user.userId.toString()
    );
    if (alreadyReviewed) {
      throw new NotFoundError('Product already reviewed');
    }
    const review = {
      user: req.user.userId,
      name: req.user.username,
      rating: Number(rating),
      comment,
    };

    product.reviews.push(review);

    product.numOfReviews = product.reviews.length;

    product.rating =
      product.reviews.reduce((acc, item) => item.rating + acc, 0) /
      product.reviews.length;

    await product.save();
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ message: 'Review added', review });
  } else {
    throw new NotFoundError('Product not found');
  }
};
```

This is mine productPage where i dispatch addProductReview and passing product id from params and review object:

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      addProductReview(id, {
        rating,
        comment,
      })
    );
  };
```

And this is my productSlice:

```
export const addProductReview = createAsyncThunk(
  'product/review',
  async (id, { review }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `/api/v1/products/${id}/reviews`,
        review
      );
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const message = error.response.data.msg;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

I have no clue why i got error Path comment is required. i pass review object to route.

Comment: In your controller, what's the value of `comment` after you destructured `req.body`?

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev Its undefined, i have state of course const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

<Form.Control
                      as='textarea'
                      rows='3'
                      value={comment}
                      onChange={e => setComment(e.target.value)}
                    />

Comment: @Phil can you write me code if you can, i don't know what you mean

Comment: What is the value of `review` in your `axios.post` call?

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev Gives me back 1,2,3,4 or 5, but comment is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the parameters used in your Thunk `payloadCreator`. From [the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)...

> The `payloadCreator` function will be called with **two arguments**:
>
> - `arg`: a single value, containing the first parameter that was passed to the thunk action creator when it was dispatched. This is useful for passing in values like item IDs that may be needed as part of the request. If you need to pass in multiple values, pass them together in an object when you dispatch the thunk, like `dispatch(fetchUsers({status: 'active', sortBy: 'name'}))`.
> - `thunkAPI`: an object containing all of the parameters that are normally passed to a Redux thunk function, as well as additional options

Your `payloadCreator` has three arguments which is incorrect.

Try this instead

```js
export const addProductReview = createAsyncThunk(
  'product/review',
  async ({ id, ...review }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `/api/v1/products/${id}/reviews`,
        review
      );
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const message = error.response.data.msg;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

and dispatch it like this

```js
dispatch(addProductReview({ id, rating, comment }));
```